Seeking to find a quote from Rashba on Kidushin

ולולא פירוש רש"י היו דברי התנאיים והאמוראים סתומות ולא היו ניתנים
להבנה
Were it nor for Rashi's commentary, Shas would remain a closed book to
us all.

I heard that the Rashba says the above in Kedushin. I searched and could not find it. I would be most appreciative if someone can direct me to this Rashba.

Where did you find the quote?

Cf. T'shuvos Rivash (394): "המאור הגדול רבינו שלמה זצ"ל גלה עמוקות התלמוד מני חשך לא עממוהו כל סתום ובזולת פירושו היה כדברי הספר החתום"

I heard it in a recorded shiur from Rabbi Yaakov Weinberg zt"l from the aishaudio library.  Great source from Rivash, would like to find this Rashba, if possible, though.
